# How can I add elements to an array in vb 2010

Tags: arrays, vb.net

Hey I got good news I am close to understanding what I need to do. I have seen a lot of data that I can use later. But right now I just need to more or less get a refresher course in this.

I need to write elements to an array. I know that part sort of..... But I won't know the array length until I run an XML file. So the file may have 1 to over 9000 (dbz). I know I will need a for loop, I just don't know how to write a for loop very well.

I got a code from the book but I don't see how I can edit this.

```
Dim arraytester() As String
For i As Integer = 0 To arraytester.Length - 1
    'little lost here 
Next
```

So how would I get around the arraytester.Length being a problem if I don't know the length of the file am am working with.

also how would I add it to the array, it is only show output in my book. (or maybe I am just losing it)

Comment: depending on how specific the assignment instructions are, consider using an `ArrayList` (`myAL.Add(thing)`); then convert it afterwards if you want: `arraytester = myAL.ToArray`.  there are lots better collections in NET than an array

Comment: Could you just use a `List(Of String)` and the `.Add()` method? Then the length becomes irrelevant.

Comment: Is this a class that requires you to use an array?

Comment: yea i got to use an array like the one above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim mylist As New List(Of String)
Using document As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create("c:\PathToYourXmlFile.xml")
    While (document.Read())
        mylist.Add(document.ReadInnerXml.ToString)
    End While
End Using
```

Since you are using the `While` loop structure, you do not need to know the amount of items in the XML file and you do not need to dimension or re-dimension the array, because the `List(Of String)` will grow as needed.

Note: The .NET 2.0 and later generic data structures are more efficient and easier to work with than array structures and even the .NET 1.x `ArrayList` data structure.

Now if you want to loop through `mylist`, then you can do this:

```
For Each item As String In mylist
    MessageBox.Show(item)
Next
```

Comment: @JohnSaunders - answer updated to use `Using` block.

Comment: trying to edit this to use it for my program. Thanks for the help.

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - thanks, did not realize that those classes were deprecated, updated to reflect that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are ways to resize arrays in VB (See `ReDim`) but it's probably better to use a `System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)` until you have collected all the elements (you can replace String with whatever element type you want to be in your array), and then you can convert the result to an array if you need it to be an array.

```
Dim arraytester() As String
Dim accumulator As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)
Do While Not input.EndOfStream
   accumulator.Add(input.ReadLine())
Loop
arraytester = accumulator.ToArray()
```

This is encouraged rather than re-sizing the array to add each element because the whole array would have to be re-allocated each time an element is added.

Answer (score 1):

If you use LINQ you can build the collection of xmlnodes and cast it to an array without knowing the upper bound of the array:

```
    Dim xdoc As New Xml.XmlDocument()
    xdoc.Load("test1.xml")
    Dim nodes() As Xml.XmlNode = (From var In xdoc.SelectNodes("doc/members/member")
                                  Let node = DirectCast(var, Xml.XmlNode)
                                 Select node).ToArray
```

Comment: Why would you use LINQ, but then use `XmlDocument` and not `XDocument`?

Comment: i would use it but i am not experienced with LINQ. And i can't use it for this class. :(

Comment: @HankBates: I was asking tinstaafl.